# Call phonegap plugin function within web app

Tags: redirect, cordova, web-applications, plugins

i am building my first phonegap app and when i open the app i instantly redirecting (window.location) the user to my server where my web app is hosted. Is it possible to load the phonegap plugins from there? Because the "deviceready" event is not firing and i cannot call any plugin functions.

Answer (score 1):

### **Short answer: Yes**

#### Some 'gotcha's'

1. You will have to supply correct cordova.js version for the platform browsing to your site.

   [you can look here for more info https://github.com/apache/cordova-js. This project hosts the core js elements, and builds the platform specific cordova.js lib](https://github.com/apache/cordova-js)
2. Any plugin api's your app wants to interact with must be pre-installed into the Native App

   any plugin with native code will have to be added to the project and deployed to device bundled inside the app. There is no way to lazyload native code. The js portions of the plugin could be hosted on your server, however.

### More information, some apps that do this

1. The [PhoneGap Developer App](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/04/23/phonegap-developer-app/) uses a similar technique to what is describe above and what you want. The only difference is that it is meant as a dev tool, and the server is a local dev machine.
2. The [Cordova App Harness](https://github.com/apache/cordova-app-harness) also uses this technique of pre-bundling an app package with plugins, to be consumed by remotely hosted resources

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that loading remotely does appear to allow access to native components (when scripts are properly loaded) and that cordova.jsdoes not appear to need to be loaded by the local index.html bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, `deviceready` only functioning if the app run on mobile phone environment only. If web based or dekstop application, it won't trigger.

Answer (score 0):

No , dont do that . loading remote website will not able to intract with your plugins . and the app will get rejected on istore too